# Why is my AASM state machine not triggered with Rails 7 Turbo patch links?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails, aasm, turbo

I just updated my Rails 6 app to Rails 7 and have problems updating my `:patch` and `:delete` links to [Turbo](https://turbo.hotwired.dev).

For example, in one of my views I have this link...

```
 link_to("Mark as sent", status_url(quote), :data => {:'turbo_method' => :patch})
```

... which is handled by this controller:

```
class StatusController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    @quote.send_it! # Should trigger AASM
    flash[:notice] = "Quote marked as sent."
    redirect_to edit_quote_path(@quote)
  end

end
```

In the model I am using [AASM](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) as a state machine:

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord

  include AASM
     
  aasm :column => "status" do
    state :draft, :initial => true
    state :inquired
    state :sent
    state :downloaded
    state :accepted
    state :rejected

    event :send_it do
      transitions :from => [:draft, :inquired], :to => :sent
    end

    ...

    event :reset_it do
      transitions :from => [:inquired, :sent, :downloaded, :accepted, :rejected], :to => :draft
    end

  end

end
```

The problem is that the state machine does not get triggered when I hit the link. The flash message and the redirect work but the state is not changed in the database. When I replace `@quote.send_it!` with `@quote.update_column(:status, "sent")`it works, however.

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in AASM that offers you dynamic methods like `:mark_as_#{status}`. I'm assuming this used to work, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Couldn't you just create a method like `@quote.mark_as(status)` that does what you want?

Comment: @Chiperific, maybe my initial post was a little misleading. I just updated my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite see how *turbo* is related. Except that I think your redirect isn't actually working:

```r
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/quotes/1/edit
Completed 302 Found in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 4.3ms | Allocations: 7265)

Started PATCH "/quotes/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-08-12 
 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/quotes/1/edit"):
# NOTE: ^ not quite a redirect

#       v but it doesn't show on a page, it just refreshes the current one.
Started GET "/quotes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-08-12 17:51:28 -0400

#       and if the current page were /quotes/1/edit then it would look like
#       redirect worked, but I was submitting from /quotes.
```

Update your controller to actually show any errors:

```rb
def update
  @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])

  # NOTE: if transition fails, `send_it!` returns `false` 
  #       (or raises an error for invalid transitions)
  #       when you run `@quote.update_column(:status, "sent")`
  #       validations and state machine are not triggered and it works.
  if @quote.send_it!
    flash.notice = "Quote marked as sent."
  else
    flash.notice = @quote.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    # in case you want add a stream response later
    # format.turbo_stream { # TODO }
    format.html { redirect_to edit_quote_path(@quote), status: :see_other }
    # NOTE: Redirect as a GET request instead of PATCH ^
  end
end
```

Or just add `whiny_persistence` flag and check the logs, this will raise validation errors:

```rb
aasm column: :status, whiny_persistence: true do
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer was an eye-opener to me since Turbo was indeed not to blame here. The `status` attribute could simply not be toggled because the record was not valid. Therefore, the status change triggered by AASM kept failing. I fixed that and it works now. Thanks for showing me how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got the `mark_as_` from, change that to `@quote.aasm.fire! status`.

### Edit

Sorry, not `status`, needs to be the event, just use the right event.

Comment: OK, I tried `@quote.aasm.fire!(:send_it)` but that doesn't work either. I also simplified my initial post above. So if you have another idea, please let me know.

Comment: So when you say it "doesn't work", what does that mean?  You have a quote in :draft or :inquired state, and you run this on it, and you get redirected, see the flash message, but the quote is still in the same state?

Comment: Precisely. The redirect + flash message works but the state remains in „draft“.

Comment: And the same code works in the rails console? (For the same quote)